# iOS Gamekit Blutooth 4+ Players?

Tags: ios, bluetooth, gamekit, multiplayer

I want to make a multiplayer game that will allow 4 people to connect their iphones together via bluetooth and play a realtime networked game.

I've been reading and reading about this, but cannot find out if it is possible. I have found documents demonstrating how you connect 2 devices via bluetooth, but I want to connect 4. Is this possible?

Can it be a host client setup, or does it have to be p2p?

Has anyone gone about implementing a 4 player multiplayer ios game over bluetooth? Can you give me any advice on how this is possible?